# Listing current Ignite jobs and cancelling them

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I got a partial answer here but not exactly what I wanted.

The link describes how to get a list of task futures but what I'd really like to be able to do is list out and cancel individual jobs (that might be hung, long running etc etc). I've seen another post implying that this is not possible but I'd like to confirm (see second link)

Thanks

1. http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/How-can-I-obtain-a-list-of-executing-jobs-on-an-ignite-node-td8841.html
2. http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Cancel-tasks-on-Ignite-compute-grid-worker-nodes-td5027.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is not possible and actually I'm not sure how this can be done in general case. Imagine there are 5 jobs running and you want to cancel one of them. How are you going to identify it? It seems to be very use case specific to me.

However, you can always implement your own mechanism to do this. One of the possible ways is to use `ComputeTaskSession` API and task attributes. E.g., set a special attribute that will act as signal for job cancellation and create attribute listener that will stop job execution accordingly.

Comment: Hi, but - as you mentioned, how would I list out jobs running per node across all nodes - in one shot ? That would be a precursor to the cancellation operation. Thx

Comment: There is no way to do this out of the box. But you can save this information somewhere (e.g. in special cache). Put some kind of ID when jobs start and remove it when job finishes.