# ComputeTaskFuture map returns futures map even when invalid nodeId cluster is specified

Tags: ignite, gridgain

```
ClusterGroup clusterGroup = ignite.cluster().forNodeIds(invalidNodeIds)
final Map<IgniteUuid, ComputeTaskFuture<Object>> computeTaskFutures = ignite.compute(clusterGroup).activeTaskFutures();
```

when fictitious invalidNodeIds are passed in, even though the backing ClusterGroupAdapter has an empty node ids (Set ids) object, I see valid futures being returned. Isn't this wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`IgniteCompute.taskFutures()` is local operation, i.e. it returns futures for tasks that were executed by the current node. Having said that, cluster group is not applicable to this method.

Comment: I thought it returns futures for all tasks within the specified cluster group . I see that the documentation says otherwise "Gets tasks future for active tasks started on local node." . That said, is there a way to get futures across all nodes ? Or even to specify which node this runs on, .. because a lot of our workers are just dumb daemon runners ready to accept work.

Comment: I see the last comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592412/listing-current-ignite-jobs-and-cancelling-them that might be useful. Else, I was pondering broadcasting the above code snippet to all nodes and collecting the results